# Unable to count images in div jquery

Tags: jquery, html, image, count

I am trying to count all *img* in a *div*.
To add images to the *div* I use a jquery function that looks like this :

```
function AddImages(namearray, amount, speed) {      
...

            }, speed)
```

All images are correctly added to the div element. [image: console.log].
After this I want to count the amount of image tags by using this :

```
var count = $("#myDiv").find('img').length;
```

OR

```
var count = document.getElementById("#myDiv").getElementsByTagName("img").length
```

Although the function AddImages() was executed before the count, this didn't worked.

Does anyone has an idea about this?

Comment: Is `speed` the related time duration after which image should be added?

Comment: do you swear that there is such a div with `myDiv` id? Maybe its id is `#myDiv` as your `document.getElementById("#myDiv")` suggests?

Comment: @Tushar, Yes it is the duration of the fadeIn effect

Comment: @n-dru, There is a div with the correct name. The value that "count" returns (console.log) is always zero.

Comment: the `speed` parameter implies there may be a timed operation in progress to add them. That would mean they are not actually added until later *after you have counted*.

Comment: ok, name might be correct, but in your 2 examples you use 2 different ids - if it is `myDiv`, the second should be `document.getElementById("myDiv")`

Comment: Add `javascript` and `html` code.

Comment: Show he DIV structure. Add markup to your code. The problem lies there.!

Comment: @Mathias Verhoeven: Without the code for `AddImages` any answers will be guesswork. Suggest you add it (before your question gets closed due to insufficient information)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the images are added over the course of a number of frames, but the function returned immediately, so no images have been added yet to count.

You can either add a callback to `AddImages` (preferred), so that you know when the images *are* all added, or simply wait for a period of time before checking (which is effectively what you did with the debugger).

e.g.

```
var i = 0;
var uniekeid = 0;
function plaatsRandomPion(naamarray, aantal, snelheid, callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        uniekeid = uniekeid + 1;
        var xpictures = Math.floor(sizepictures * Math.random())
        var item = $("<img src='" + naamarray[xpictures] + "' id='" + uniekeid + "' />").hide().fadeIn();
        $('#depionnen').append(item);
        console.log(item);

        i++;
        if (i < aantal) {
            plaatsRandomPion(naamarray, aantal, snelheid, callback);
        }
        else {
            // We are done... callback to let the caller know
            // Note: check whether the callback exists first
            callback && callback();
        }
    }, snelheid)

}
```

And call like this:

```
plaatsRandomPion(pictures, 20, 100, function(){
    var count = $("#box").find('img').length;
    // Now the count will be set!
});
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/kcffgq26/4/

*A more "modern" solution would be to use jQuery promises, but that is too much for this simple problem for now.*

Note: having global settings outside a function (e.g. `uniekeid` & `i`) is usually a sign of *non-reusable* code. You can get the same effect, with no counters, by simply reducing the array each time with `slice` and passing the shorter array recursively until it is empty. As you appear to want a random selection of images, I would suggest randomly sorting the array first (to avoid duplicate images).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. Unfortunately I've still an error in the console.log : "undefined is not a function (evaluating 'callback()')" Do I need to make the callback function myself or is it part of jQuery?

Comment: @Mathias Verhoeven: The last part of the example passes an anonymous function as the callback parameter. Follow that pattern. I have also added a safety check on the `callback` so you could use it without a callback parameter if needed.

Comment: I've done it exactly like your example.  Can you take a look at it please? This is the website with full code : [link] (http://www.testing.opticveronique.be)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ Mathias Verhoeven: You simply miss-typed `length` as `lenght`! :)

Comment: I did indeed, sorry. The console log doesn't appear. There must be something else that's wrong

Comment: @Mathias Verhoeven: Can you mockup a JSFiddle of just the image code, using your styling and HTML from your page? That will make debugging a lot easier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76164/discussion-between-mathias-verhoeven-and-trueblueaussie).

Comment: Ah, my bad, forgot to pass the callback on the recursive call. Answer updated. Note: I added and used a missing var for the length for now.